# Mplayer in slave mode draws ontop of GTK# widgets

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk#, mplayer

I'm trying to use mPlayer in slave mode (*-slave with a wid attached to a gtk# socket, in an event box*) with a transparent eventbox on top of it, with a transparent png.

This works when it's not set to be a transparent eventbox, but when it *is* a transparent event box, mPlayer draws ontop of the widget.

I have a Fixed container, containing both EventBoxes. The Mplayer eventbox is Put first, then the image box.

The EventBox containing the image has `visible = true` and `visibleWindow = false` to make it transparent.

This works to overlay the image ontop of any other type of content.

`If visibleWindow = true`, the image displays over the video.

This works fine on Windows, but I'm trying to get this working in linux.